# Python gnomekeyring get Attributes of key

Tags: python, gnome

How can I access the attributes of an key saved in the Gnome keyring with Python using the module gnomekeyring?

I created the key with the following code and want to access database_ip and database_user

```
import gnomekeyring


attributes = {
    'database_ip'   : "localhost",
    'database_name' : "test",
    'database_user' : "test"
    }

gnomekeyring.item_create_sync('login', gnomekeyring.ITEM_GENERIC_SECRET, "mynewkey", attributes, "mysecretpassword", True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the attributes with:

```
gnomekeyring.item_get_attributes_sync('login', key_id)
```

Example:

```
key_names = {}
key_ids = gnomekeyring.list_item_ids_sync('login')
for key_id in key_ids:
    key_info = gnomekeyring.item_get_info_sync('login', key_id)
    key_names[key_info.get_display_name()]=key_id

if "mynewkey" in key_names.keys():
    key_attributes = gnomekeyring.item_get_attributes_sync('login', key_names["mynewkey"])
    print key_attributes["database_ip"]
    print key_attributes["database_user"]
```